# open class UIButton trying to change view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, protocols, viewcontroller

So i have a UIButton with its own custom class (open class circlemenu: UIButton), the button is placed on a view controller but the code for the button is in a seperate swift file.

as the custom class produces results i would like it to change from the viewcontroller where the button is physically place to another viewcontroller.

at them moment I'm just getting an error as i can't do like i normally would from a VC item as the button has no self??:

```
class circlemenu {
    var parentViewController:UIViewController!

    func presentNewViewController() {
        let newViewController = parentViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR STORYBOARD ID") as UIViewController
        parentViewController.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

i have also tried setting up a relationship with the unbutton and the viewcontroller with the following in my custom class

```
var parentViewController:UIViewController!

func presentNewViewController() {
    let newViewController = parentViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardID") as UIViewController
    parentViewController.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and this in the viewcontroller class

```
func myCustomClass() {
    var customButton = circlemenu()
    customButton.parentViewController = self
}
```

but it just keeps throwing me errors.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the problem you are facing? Not able to get what you mean by saying 'at them moment I'm just getting an error as i can't do like i normally would from a VC item as the button has no self??'

Comment: I agree, a bit confusing. You don't place a UIButton on a view controller, you place it on a view. But if the issue is *how does a UIButton on one view update something on another view*, I'd search this site as it's been answered a few times in the last month or two.